# Any metrics could measure vignetting effect of images?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I would like to detect the pictures suffered by Vignetting or not, but cannot find a way to measure it. I search by keywords like "Vignetting metrics, Vignetting detection, Vignetting classification", they all lead me to topics like "Create vignetting filters" or "Vignetting correction". Any metric could do that? Like score from 0 to 1, the lower the score, the more unlikely the images suffered from vignetting effect. One of the naive solution I come up is measure the Luminance channel of the image.

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto img = imread("my_pic.jpg");
    cvtcolor(img, img, cv::COLOR_BGR2LAB);
    vector<Mat> lab_img;
    split(img, lab_img);
    auto const sum_val = sum(lab_img[0])[0] / lab_img[0].total();
    //use sum_val as threshold
}
```

Another solution is trained a classifier by CNN, I could use the vignetting filter to generate images with/without vignetting effect. Please give me some suggestions, thanks.

[image: vig_00][image: vig_01]

Comment: can you show some sample input? You could trace the intensity from image center to the outside and search for a decreasing tendency. But not sure about how to get rid of the "content" and just measure general brightness. Maybe some low-pass-filtering?

Comment: Vignetting depends on a bunch of things. You might get a reasonable solution if you have a generalized vignetting model based on center offset, skew, aspect ratio, aperture, focal length, sensor size and vignette strength. Your image metadata might already hint at some of these values which will inform the model better. Then just solve/fit the model from the image luminance. The solver would score image uniformity after correcting vignetting based on the model. So you'd still need a metric for uniformity, maybe based on subdividing into multiple zones.

Comment: @paddy Sounds like a job more suitable for machine learning.

Comment: @paddy Are you suggesting that OP uses a known vignette strength to determine if the image has vignetting? I'm not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: This is the same as the problem of determining if the image is in focus or not. It depends on the contents, and so there is no general solution. Is it an image with vignetting of a uniform background, or is it an image of a non-uniform background that just happens to look like vignetting? Typically, vignetting is corrected by characterizing the lens. A particular sense will always cause exactly the same amount of vignetting, and so you can correct for it blindly. If you don't know what lens was used, or you don't know it characteristics, then all you can do is guess.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks, this problem is much difficult than I though. I don't have any information of the lens, and the contents could be anything, my best bet maybe is train a classifier by cnn.

Comment: this doesn't need ML. this needs a polar warp, some masking, and some simple statistics.

Comment: to be fair, throwing ML at this might make things easier. AI can understand picture content better, and separate _its_ contribution to pixel intensities from the contribution of the vignette effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a polar warp and some simple statistics on the picture. You'll get a plot of the radial intensities. You'll see the characteristic attenuation of a vignette, but also picture content. This 1D signal is easier to analyze than the entire picture.

This is not guaranteed to always work. I'm not saying it should. It's an approach.

Variations are conceivable that use medians, averages, ... but then you'd have to introduce a mask too, so you know what pixels are coming from the image and which ones are just out-of-bounds black (to be ignored). You can extend the source image to 4-channel, with the fourth channel being all-255. The warp will treat that as any other color channel, so you'll get a "valid"-mask out of it that you can use.

I am confronting you with Python because it's about the idea and the APIs, and I categorically refuse to do prototyping/research in C++.

```py
(h,w) = im.shape[:2]

im = np.dstack([im, np.full((h,w), 255, dtype=np.uint8)]) # 4th channel will be "valid mask"

rmax = np.hypot(h, w) / 2

(cx, cy) = (w-1) / 2, (h-1) / 2

# dsize
dh = 360 * 2
dw = 1000

# need to explicitly initialize that because the warp does NOT initialize out-of-bounds pixels
warped = np.zeros((dh, dw, 4), dtype=np.uint8)

cv.warpPolar(dst=warped, src=im, dsize=(dw, dh), center=(cx,cy), maxRadius=int(rmax), flags=cv.INTER_LANCZOS4)

values = warped[..., 0:3]
mask = warped[..., 3]

values = cv.cvtColor(values, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

picture 1:

[image: values 1] [image: mask 1]

picture 2:

[image: values 2] [image: mask 2]

```py
mvalues = np.ma.masked_array(values, mask=(mask == 0))

# numpy only has min/max/median for masked arrays
# need this for quantile/percentile
# this selects the valid pixels for every column
cols = (col.compressed() for col in mvalues.T)
cols = [col for col in cols if len(col) > 0]
```

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6), dpi=150)
plt.xlim(0, dw)

for p in [0, 10, 25, 50, 75, 90, 100]:
    plt.plot([np.percentile(col, p) for col in cols if len(col) > 0], 'k', linewidth=0.5, label=f'{p}%')

plt.plot(mvalues.mean(axis=0), 'red', linewidth=2, label='mean')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Plot for first picture:

[image: plot 1]

Plot for second picture:

[image: plot 2]